# How rare is it to get a Mending book from a villager for 7 emeralds on 3rd roll?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am on Bedrock edition and it was my first time doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You had a 2.8% chance of rolling mending on your third villager.

Explanation: If I counted correctly, there are 106 possible enchanted books (including different levels) that a villager can trade. Thus mending has a 1 in 106 chance of appearing. Mending has a cost of between 10 and 38 emeralds, with the chance of cost evenly distributed.

7 emeralds is apparently impossible (without any trading discounts) according to the wiki, though the wiki is generally more accurate for java than bedrock.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#cite_note-enchanted-book-8 (note 7)